# What is the Grooviest way to model this data?

Tags: java, groovy, object-model

I am using Groovy to read from a CSV file which has the below fields:

```
  Code   Name        Class
  ---    -----       ----
  1701   Enterprise  Constitution      
  1864   Reliant     Miranda
```

What is the best way to represent this data in Groovy?

I was thinking a `HashMap` where *Code* is the key and the value is a POGO with two fields (*Name* and *Class*). But is there a groovier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a plain `Map` with `code` as a key is ok enough. It depends on what you need to do exactly. If you need to transform this data into `Map` that's the way to go.

However groovy is so elastic in data processing that you can also create a POGO and transform this CSV data into a list. It can be easily grouped by `code` or whatever you need.

Also, maybe creating a POGO isn't necessary? In such case use `code` a a key to.. `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

With a POGO and the [`TupleConstructor`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) AST transformation, parsing CSV into a list is usually quite straightforward:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-csv', version='1.2')
)

import groovy.transform.*
import org.apache.commons.csv.*

@ToString
@TupleConstructor
class Test {
    int code
    String name
    String type
}

def text = ''' Code,Name,Class
1701,Enterprise,Constitution
1864,Reliant,Miranda'''

def parsed = CSVParser.parse(text, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces().withQuote(null))

def result = parsed.getRecords().collect { new Test(it.Code as int, it.Name, it['Class']) }
assert '[Test(1701, Enterprise, Constitution), Test(1864, Reliant, Miranda)]' == result.toString()
assert 'Enterprise' == result.find({ it.code == 1701 }).name
```